# If I call setneedsdisplay frequently, how often will the drawrect be called? why is that?

Tags: ios, drawrect, setneedsdisplay

In my case, the `drawRect:` will not be called immediately after every single `setNeedsDisplay` is called. For example, I think the following code is same as my case.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: Which is exactly what you want, so that iOS doesn't kill your performance.

Comment: @gnasher729 I receive some serial points data from server, and draw a line   in `drawRect:` according to these points, but some special points need to be handled specially. so when  a special point comes, I call 'setNeedsDisplay', but it happens not to call 'drawRect:'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html):

> When the actual content of your view changes, it is your responsibility to notify the system that your view needs to be redrawn. You do this by calling your view’s setNeedsDisplay or setNeedsDisplayInRect: method of the view. These methods let the system know that it should update the view during the next drawing cycle. **Because it waits until the next drawing cycle to update the view, you can call these methods on multiple views to update them at the same time.**

`drawRect:` will only be called in time for the next frame to be drawn, which means your entire loop will result in `drawRect:` only being called once at the next rendering iteration. This saves unnecessary computation as it avoids drawing frames that will never be displayed on the screen. It also lets you make multiple changes in separate places in your code, each time notifying the view that a refresh is needed, without losing performance, since **calling `setNeedsDisplay` only tells the drawing system that a redraw is needed in the next frame; it doesn't force the immediate rendering of a frame that might never be displayed on the screen.**

Answer (score 1):

`setNeedsDisplay` only *marks* the view as needing to be displayed again. The actual drawing call is done in the next runloop iteration of the main thread, *once*. This allows the drawing system to do some optimizations and "combine" repeated calls to `setNeedsDisplay`.